# Android SDK is not installing on my Eclipse mars

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm fairly new with eclipse and Android programming in general. SO i decided to use some guides to help me install it.

I've already installed and followed several guides but errors always appear on my Console window:

Right now, every time i try to run the android virtual device manager(on Window tab) i get the following message:

[2016-02-28 06:19:56 - SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml

[2016-02-28 06:19:56 - SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

I tried to install this thing 7 times and so far the only thing that changes are the errors i get.
Some people recommended me to use Android Studio but every book and tutorial I've found so far only uses Eclipse to teach.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I'm honest, I'd try Android Studio - you won't look back! I wouldn't worry much that these tutorials are using eclipse - the code won't be different, just the IDE. To be honest these tutorials maybe slightly dated if they're using Eclipse - better to learn Android Studio straight off the bat, if its not the standard already, it soon will be.

Comment: Eclipse is no longer officially supported. The last ADT plugin for eclipse was released in August 2015, I think. You should start with Android Studio, and as Mark said above, the code will not change, only the IDE will. Moreover Eclipse + Android has long been plagued by subtle but annoying bugs (R.java bug for starters).

Comment: Ok, so do you guys recommend any books or tutorials on the subject?

Comment: What is your current level? Do you have experience with Java? I'd recommend the book: Head First Java and have a look through the Android Developers website that has an absolute wealth of information and lots of small tutorials http://developer.android.com/index.html